# Why the p in "receipt" is not pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, etymology

Is there any known pronunciation rule that justifies the p in "receipt" not being pronounced, does it have to do with the origin of the word or something or how it is? Why the p in "receipt" is not pronounced?

Comment: Fyi,that is called a silent p. Like the l in would and should. Also silent.

Comment: There are two different pronunciations of _receipt_. One is /ri'sit/, where the P is not pronounced, and the other is /'rɛsəpi/, as an alternate spelling of _recipe_. In that one the T is not pronounced. The fact is that letters in English spelling do not represent the pronunciation of English words, no matter what your English teacher told you. Sorry about that. Spellings and pronunciations have to be learned separately. This saves time over following spelling rules, because there are too many random exceptions to all of the rules, and all of those exceptions have to be learned separately.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Can you give a reference for pronouncing "receipt" as  /'rɛsəpi/? The word "receipt" has been used to *mean* "recipe", but as far as I know it was usually pronounced the same as for other meanings of the word *receipt.* http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-rec1.htm

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not sure I understand what you're saying in your first two sentences. *Receipt* is pronounced one way, and *recipe* another. *Receipt* and *recipe* are different lexemes.

Comment: Please always wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer (you never know who might want to add something, and not everyone's here all the time). You'll find other good reasons listed in this [meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), which I encourage you to read. (Please don't mistake this as saying that the currently accepted answer is bad.) Nice question, by the way. Also, if you're interested in detailed etymologies and so on, you might wanna consider asking such questions on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My grandparents (in the UK) both pronounced "recipe" (i.e. a cookery recipe) as "receipt" - which is the opposite way round from John Lawler's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Receipt" is pretty much just an exceptional case. The word is pronounced without a /p/ sound because it comes from French *receite/recete*. It is spelled with a P based on its etymology from Latin *receptus.*

It's not entirely random, but it's certainly irregular: the words *conceit* and *deceit* have analogous histories, but aren't spelled with P, and the word *concept* is both spelled with the letter P and pronounced with the sound /p/.

There is a small set of words like this with "etymologically" inserted silent letters. (Most "silent" letters in English are of other types, e.g. the so-called "silent e" that functions in many words as a marker of vowel "length".) Some of the etymologies aren't even accurate: probably the most infamous example is the "silent s" in the spelling of the word *island.*

Since many people tend to emphasize the "unpredictability" of English spelling in discussions of words like this, I'd like to stress that words with completely irregular "silent" letters like this really are uncommon. English spelling is certainly complicated, but most of the complications are related to semi-regular patterns (e.g. consonant doubling or systematic ambiguities in the spelling of certain sounds), not one-off oddities like this.